# How to convert Utf8 file to CP1252 by Unix

Tags: oracle, unix, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to transform txt file encoding from UTF8 to ANSI (cp1252).

I need this because the file is used in a fixed position Oracle import (external Table) which apparently only supports CP1252.  If I import an UTF-8 file, some special characters turn up as two incorrect characters instead.

I'm working in a Unix machine (my OS is HP UX). I have been looking for an answer on the web but I don't find any way to do this conversion.

For exmple, the POSIX `iconv` command doesn't have this choose, in fact UTF8 is used only as "to" encoding (`-t`) but never as "from" encoding (`-f`). `iconv -l` returns a long list with conversion pairs but UTF8 is always only in the second column.

How can I convert my file to CP1252 by UNIX?

Comment: UTF-8 is not listed as a "to" encoding because you can lose information going to that form.

Comment: @ThomasDickey do you mean the other way round? That you can lose info going from UTF8 to CP1252?

Comment: yes - hands faster than brain :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UTF-8 file only contains characters which are also representable as CP1252, you should be able to perform the conversion.

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1252 <file.utf8 >file.txt
```

If, however, the UTF-8 text contains some characters which cannot be represented as CP1252, you have a couple of options:

- Convert anyway, and have the converter omit the problematic characters
- Convert anyway, and have the converter replace the problematic characters

This should be a conscious choice, so out of the box, `iconv` doesn't allow you to do this; but there are options to enable this behavior.  Look at the `-c` option for the first behavior, and `--unicode-subst` for the second.

```
bash$ echo 'x≠y' | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1252
x
iconv: (stdin):1:1: cannot convert

bash$ echo 'x≠y' | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1252 -c
xy

bash$ echo 'x≠y' | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1252 --unicode-subst='?'
x?y
```

This is on OS X; apparently, Linux `iconv` lacks some of these options.  Maybe look at [`recode`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/recode) and/or write your own simple conversion tool if you don't get the behavior you need out of `iconv` on your platform.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252', 'replace'))
```

Put `'ignore`' instead of `'replace'` to drop characters which cannot be represented.  The default replacement character is `?` like in the `iconv` example above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this Java converter: [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html)
It is part of JDK installation.

The conversion is done in two steps:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 <your_file.txt> <your_file.txt.ascii>
native2ascii -reverse -encoding windows-1252 <your_file.txt.ascii> <your_file_new.txt>
```

Characters which are used in UTF-8 but not supported in CP1252 (including [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) are replaced by `?`

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? Java is available also for Unix, mostly it is installed by default. And it works - I tested it. For example `€` character was converted properly.